# Fresh Install of 16.04 First Login Failure

Tags: login, password, 16.04

I installed a fresh 16.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad 300 i5 Skylake.

During installation I entered a user name and password. 
The installation concluded fine and asked me to reboot.
Did the reboot.
Got to the login screen, wrote the password and the system responds that it's wrong.

I installed again, this time making absolutely sure there were no password errors. Same thing.

I installed yet again, this time tagging off the password at login, entered the system and all was well but the problem persisted. In terminal when I tried to execute a sudo command, the password I know for a fact is right, turned out wrong.

What is going on? 
Is there a default password that I'm not aware of?

Comment: this may sound weird but ... have you tried inverting the capitalization .. in other words if your password was HiWorld ... did you dry hIwORLD? ... maybe something got thrown off and your keyboard acted differently when creating the password then it does when Ubuntu is fully installed... its a long shot but worth a try .. if so you could just create a new password

Comment: tried, no go.
did an all numbers dumbed down password. 123123
and still nada.

Comment: at this point I would probably try a LiveCD not actually sure if you can do it but I wonder if you could create a new user with the LiveCD and then try to see if that user can log in with the password. Again .. not sure its possible to create a user with the livecd though.. this is a complete guess